# Lua key name starts with digit in table statement

Tags: lua

When key name starts with digit, in javascript we can define array-like object like this:

```
var table = {
    '123.com': 'details'
    '456.net': 'info'
}
```

But when I try these code in Lua5.1:

```
table = { '123.com' = 'info' }
```

It throws an error:

```
[string "local"]:1: '}' expected near '='
```

But these code are accepted in lua:

```
table = {}
table['123.com'] = 'info'
```

I wonder if it is a bug in Lua5.1. Or did I missed something?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When creating a Lua table using the literal table constructor, non-identifier table indices should be enclosed in square brackets. For example:

`table = { ['123.com'] = 'info' }`

(From: http://www.lua.org/pil/3.6.html)